# JavaScript based breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, jquery, breadcrumbs

I have HTML code:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Library</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Data</a></li>
</ul>
```

which I want to be changed by JavaScript based on javascript $currentPath variable which stores string like this: "/var/www/stackoverflow"
So in example above my breadcrumbs should look like:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">var</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">www</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">stackoverflow</a></li>
</ul>
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split the variable like this.

```
var url = $currentPath.split('/'); //now url = ["", "var", "www", "stackoverflow"]
var breadcrumb = '';
//Use a for loop
for(var i=0;i<url.lenght;i++){
  if(url[i]!=''){
    breadcrumb = '<li><a href="#">'+url[i]+'</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To outline the process for you:

1. `split` the `$currentPath` string on `'/'`. This gives you an array (of crumbs).
2. `for each` element in the array:

   1. `create` (or `clone`) a `<li>`-element to your liking, setting its contents as you need.
   2. `append` your new `<li>` the `<ul>` list.

Feel free to ask if you want details, otherwise enjoy working it out ;)

Google:

- `mdn split`
- `jquery clone`
- `jquery text`
- `jquery append`